# django "GeometryField" widget type to accept coordinates in floating point format

Tags: geodjango

I'm trying to make a django form for user to specify the coordinates on a map and i did this by including small map widget where it's possible to choose geometry type as well as put it on map. But i'm looking for some widget where i can choose geometry type (like LineString, Point, Polygon) and specify values in separate field. Is there any existing solutions for this or i should add my own custom fields?

Now i have this form field:

```
geometry = forms.GeometryField(required=False)
```